# can't open any files in bash script: no such file or directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I am trying to open a text file in a bash script on ubuntu 20.04.
The bash script looks as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

"gedit /home/usr/textfile.txt"
```

I get the following output when running the bash script:

```
./test.sh: line 3: gedit /home/usr/textfile.txt: No such file or directory
```

when entering the command into the terminal by hand, everything works just fine. I've tried using a multitude of different shebangs, but that didn't help. I guess it's got to be a fairly obvious mistake here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"gedit /home/usr/textfile.txt" is a string and not a command name to execute string you can do $("gedit /home/usr/textfile.txt") or remove quote around

```
#!/bin/bash

gedit /home/usr/textfile.txt
```

Comment: thanks, that solved it. One more question: If i just write "gedit" into the script without the path, it opens gedit with an empty file. How come that the execution works in this case but not if a path is involved?

Comment: it's because he try to execute the string as a complete command name "gedit" exist on your system (with `which gedit` you will see the path) but "gedit /home/usr/textfile.txt" is not a command name he don't parse it but try to execute it as a command (`which "gedit /home/usr/textfile.txt"` will return nothing)

Answer (score 1):

Any command you'll want to enter in a shell script shouldn't have quotes like you showed above. Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euxo pipefail
gedit /home/usr/textfile.txt
```

The `-euxo pipefail` is really helpful and I include it in all of my shell scripts.  You can find more info about it here, https://transang.me/best-practice-to-make-a-shell-script/.

Also, since you're scripting a file, you might want to add in either a `sed` command to search and edit or an echo to edit the file inside of the script.

```
read -r -d '' /home/usr/textfile.txt << EOF
Hello new line
EOF
```